# Simple MySQL Subquery Performance

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

Consider the 2 MySQL queries:

```
SELECT ue.userid,e.courseid 
FROM (SELECT id,courseid FROM mdl_enrol WHERE status = 0 AND courseid IN (46)) e 
INNER JOIN (SELECT enrolid,userid FROM mdl_user_enrolments ) ue ON ue.enrolid = e.id 
INNER JOIN (SELECT userid FROM mdl_userdata) ud ON ue.userid = ud.userid
```

--

```
SELECT ue.userid,e.courseid 
FROM mdl_enrol e 
INNER JOIN mdl_user_enrolments ue ON ue.enrolid = e.id 
INNER JOIN mdl_userdata ud ON ue.userid = ud.userid
WHERE e.status = 0 AND e.courseid IN (46)
```

The bottom query is much much faster than the top query, but why? I've read that to increase performance you should only select the columns you need. Also, to me the top query should perform better because in each JOIN, you're reducing the amount of data you're joining. Obviously my understanding of how databases work is wrong, but if anyone could clear this up it would be much appreciated. An EXPLAIN also confirms that the bottom query is much faster.

Many thanks.

Comment: "to increase performance you should only select the columns you need" --- and to increase performance you should avoid using subqueries :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first query mysql should select a subset from `mdl_enrol` table and **complete** `mdl_user_enrolments` and `mdl_userdata` into the memory. So you select a lot of data in memory. After you've done that - you join the data. If there is not enough memory to put all the data until it's joined and sent back to the client - then temporary table on the hard drive is created. Most likely mysql optimizer isn't cool enough to fix your mistake and try to improve execution plan. That's why it's slow.

Whereas for the second query mysql knows what exactly it needs to select and only selects the small amount of required data. In this scenario it's possible to use indexes (assuming all the necessary indexes have been created). So it's fast.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So basically if you avoid subqueries, it's less likely that MySQL will need to create temporary tables (once the memory is full). And also, indexes are less effective, or not effective at all, when using subqueries?

Comment: @paul78: with some approximation - yes. The query optimization process  is terribly difficult, but avoiding subqueries is a good rule of thumb. Though there are valid cases for subqueries - but it's another story ;-)