# For each country, find the average weight of ships that have visited the country

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Tried solving it using the following `LEFT JOIN` but got stuck after that

```
SELECT COUNTRY FROM VISIT LEFT JOIN S ON S.CRUISENUM=VISIT.CRUISENUM (SELECT SHIP.SHIPNUM , WEIGHT , CRUISENUM FROM CRUISE LEFT JOIN SHIP ON CRUISE.SHIPNUM = SHIP.SHIPNUM) AS S
```

[image]

Comment: Please improve formatting of your question to increase the chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make two joins in the same query, there's no need to make a subquery.

```
     SELECT V.COUNTRY, AVG(S.WEIGHT)
       FROM visit V
  LEFT JOIN cruise C ON ( C.CRUISENUM = V.CRUISENUM )
  LEFT JOIN ship   S ON ( S.SHIPNUM = C.SHIPNUM )
   GROUP BY V.COUNTRY
```

Comment: hello do you know how can i remove hold from my previous question

Comment: tried solving it using the follow :

not working with me

 select builder from ship where max(weight) in
(select SUM(WEIGHT) from ship group by builder)
List the names of cruise directors who have visited at least two different countries. I tried this code but it didn't work for me as well

    SELECT DISTINCT C1.DIRECTOR
FROM CRUISE C1 , CRUISE C2
WHERE C1.DIRECTOR =C2.DIRECTOR AND C1.SHIPNUM = C2.SHIPNUM

Comment: can you check  my other queries down below . thanks

Answer (score 0):

Avoid sub-queries unless they are really needed. You were onto the right solution with a JOIN. (But you don't need a left join because if the `ship` record doesn't exist then you don't want to calculate anything.)

```
SELECT COUNTRY, AVG(weight)
FROM VISIT
JOIN CRUISE USING (cruisenum)
JOIN SHIP USING (shipnum)
GROUP BY COUNTRY
```

Comment: can you check  my other queries down below . thanks

Comment: Even when not *needed*, subqueries can provide tremendous performance benefits. That said, I agree with the principle of learning to do things 'old school' and then introducing new(er) techniques.

Comment: @Strawberry, yes, in certain specific circumstances sub-queries can help. However, those are fairly specialized and the general rule, particularly for those starting out with SQL, should be to try to do it without sub-queries. It's not "old school" - it's good practice unless you really know what you're doing and what those specific cases are. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365907/simple-mysql-subquery-performance

Answer (score 0):

**Largest builder by total weight**

```
select builder from ship where max(weight) in
(select SUM(WEIGHT) from ship group by builder)
```

**List the names of cruise directors who have visited at least two different countries.** I tried this code but it didn't work for me as well

```
 SELECT DISTINCT C1.DIRECTOR
FROM CRUISE C1 , CRUISE C2
WHERE C1.DIRECTOR =C2.DIRECTOR AND C1.SHIPNUM = C2.SHIPNUM
```

Comment: this is my other quries

Comment: Asking another question as an answer to your own question isn't the SO way... :-)